# How can I resize a tool window in IntelliJ IDEA using the keyboard?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using the JetBrains IDE, how can i resize the intellij idea project panel ,project panel and other panels using just the keyboard

My IntelliJ build is : IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2

Comment: Any special reasons why you want to use the keyboard?

Comment: just to avoid using mouse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Outdated**

For IntelliJ 2017.1.2, to resize a Tool window, hold <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> and use the arrow keys to either shrink or expand the window.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/01/resize-tool-windows-with-keyboard/

**Update for IntelliJ 2022.2**

macOS:

- To resize a vertical tool window, press `⌃ ⌥ ←` and `⌃ ⌥ →`
- To resize a horizontal tool window, press `⌃ ⌥ ↑` and `⌃ ⌥ ↓`

Windows:

- To resize a vertical tool window, press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Left` and `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Right`
- To resize a horizontal tool window, press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Up` and `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Down`

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html?keymap=secondary_macos#advanced-features

Comment: Cmd-Shift + arrow keys on mac. Note that the window you want to resize needs to have the focus. Beware that using Cmd+Shift + up or down keys while the cursor is on a method declaration will move the method up and down in the class while being inside a method will move the currently selected line(s) up or down

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 :( I redeclared the shortcut to other combination (because ctrl+shift+l/r arrow moves caret with selection) and still it does not work - should I file a bug to Jetbrains?

Comment: Neither work on linux mint. Same behavior as on ubuntu. In addition, `ctrl` + `alt` + `shift` + `arrowkeys` just change OS cinnamon workspace.

Comment: @selan Hi Selan, I've updated my answer to reflect the latest IntelliJ version. Can you try again?

Answer (score 3):

This is an update as Luciano's answer does not work for me: on 2021.2.2, in the windows keymap, the default is `Ctrl`+ `Alt` + `Shift` + `arrowKey`. You can also change it there.

[image]